# How can I select items in an each block?

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I select items in an `each` block? Or, to think of it in the opposite way, how can I modify items within a `select` block?

As an example, given an array of integers, how can I reject odd numbers, returning an array of the even numbers, while adding 10 to them? In the following example, I'd want `[12, 14, 16]` to be returned.

Trying with `select`:

```
a = (1..6).to_a
a.select! do |i|
  if i % 2 == 0
    a[a.find_index(i)] += 10 # This doesn't stick.
    true # this works
  end
end
p a # => [2, 4, 6]
```

Trying with `each`:

```
a = (1..6).to_a
a.each do |i|
  if i % 2 == 0
    a[a.find_index(i)] += 10
  else
    a.delete(a.find_index(i)) # I suppose this isn't working?
  end
end
p a # => [1, 12, 3, 14, 5, 16]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map!` to transform the members of the array - instead of setting the new value in the array you simply return what you want the new value to be from the block. For the values you want to reject you return `nil`.

```
a = (1..6).to_a
a.map! do|i|
  if i % 2 == 0
    i + 10
  end
end.compact!
p a # => [12, 14, 16]
```

#### UPDATE:

Since the issue of multiple passes came up alot, here is a single-pass solution with flat_map:

```
a = (1..6).to_a
a = a.flat_map do|i|
  if i.even? #happy?
    [i + 10]
  else
    []
  end
end
p a # => [12, 14, 16]
```

Sadly, there is no `flat_map!` so we have to reassign `a`.

Comment: Perfect! Very elegant (in my case the array is nil-free to start, so this is fine).

Comment: Since we're doing two passes through the array anyway in this solution, I think the other solution by `miluz` is much more readable for the same performance characteristics.

Comment: Instead using `i % 2 == 0` you can replace it with `i.even?`

Comment: @Jesper I probably could have given a better example, but this suits me better, because I can use variables restricted to each item within this block.

Comment: As per my [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759702/how-can-i-select-items-in-an-each-block/25782523?noredirect=1#comment40331419_25782523) below, `inject` is 35% slower than `map!.compact!`. I also benchmarked `flat_map`, and that was 70% slower. I'm a bit surprised, but the double-pass solution seems the most efficient.

Comment: @Sparhawk it's because `flat_map` and `inject` create new lists while `map!.compact!` mutates the existing list. If you were to use `map.compact` and assign the result back to `a`, it'll probably be much slower.

Comment: Interesting. You are correct to a certain degree. `a = map.compact` is 14% slower than `map!.compact!`. It's interesting though, that it's still quicker than the other two.

Comment: That's weird. I would assume that haveing to create two more lists will make it slower than the one-pass solutions that only need to allocate one big list... Maybe Ruby can optmize `map` because it knows in advance the size of the new list it needs to allocate? I'm not sure about `compact`, but since it's such a simple function I guess Ruby can optimize it as well...

Answer (score 2):

You can use select to remove all the odd numbers, and use map to perform the additional operation you want:

```
a.select { |x| x % 2 == 0 }.map { |x| x + 10 }
=> [12, 14, 16]
```

Comment: Ruby have in-built method `.even?`. `select { |x| x % 2 == 0 }` -> `select(&:even?)`

Comment: Nice answer (+1), but I will accept the other one. For my purposes, part of the problem is having variables within a single block, so it works a bit better for me.

Comment: @Зелёный The even/odd thing was just a dummy example. I was more interested in a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

As a curiosity, you can also use Ruby's lazy enumerations in Ruby >= 2.

```
mega_range = (1..100_000)

filtered_collection = mega_range.lazy.select do |n|
    puts "selecting #{n}"
    n.even?
end.map do |n|
    puts "mapping #{n}"
    n * 2
end

filtered_collection.take(10).to_a

# selecting 1
# selecting 2
# mapping 2
# selecting 3
# selecting 4
# mapping 4
# selecting 5
# selecting 6
# mapping 6
# selecting 7
# selecting 8
# mapping 8
#  => [4, 8, 12, 16]
```

As you can see, the `select` and `map` operations are merged, with `map` only done on the selected events.

No need for an extra pass through the collection (which is what `compact!` does).

Comment: This looks really interesting, but doesn't seem to work; I don't get any output. If I remove `.lazy` (and reduce the range), it works as expected (while obviously processing the whole range). With `.lazy` included, the final output is not an array, but `#<Enumerator::Lazy: #<Enumerator::Lazy: #<Enumerator::Lazy: #<Enumerator::Lazy: 1..20>:select>:map>:take(10)>`

Comment: Ah okay, it doesn't evaluate the first section as is, but does if you convert `filtered_collection` from an enumerable by (e.g.) appending `.to_a` to the final line.

Comment: Yeah, I'll add that call to `.to_a`

Comment: Thanks for that. Thanks also for making me interested in `lazy` (+1), although I did some benchmarking and found it considerable slower than without.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to achieve your goal with only select, that can not modify any element.

Below are other alternatives (may duplicates with some answers above):

```
ary = (1..6).to_a

ary.map! { |x| x.even? ? x + 10 : nil }.compact!
ary.keep_if { |x| x.even? }.map! { |x| x + 10 }
ary.delete_if { |x| x.odd? }.map! { |x| x + 10 }
ary = ary.inject([]) { |final, element| element.even? ? final.push(element + 10) : final }

p ary # => [12, 14, 16]
```

Comment: Mostly this has been implied in other answers, but +1 for the inject version. That is very nice. Allows me to use variables in a single block, and iterates over the array only once.

Comment: Having said that, I benchmarked the `inject` version against the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25759837/1944384) and it was 35% slower (for an array up to 10,000,000). It seems that iterating at the end is quicker than running both steps for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try this:

```
>> (1..6).select(&:even?).map { |x| x + 10 }
=> [12, 14, 16]
```

Comment: Please take the time to read the other answers and comments before posting. You didn't add anything relevant to the discussion.

Comment: I show the another easy way to achieve expected answer.. Is this Wrong??

Comment: I'd argue that what you propose has already been discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25759849/648392